# how to add text in static map api

Tags: google-maps-static-api

how to add text in map image using  google static map

this my url:
[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=13.0171749,80.2604959%7C13.0962573,80.2495762999999&size=400x400&markers=icon:https://ia601509.us.archive.org/18/items/pickup_20180122/pickup.png%7C13.0171749,80.2604959&markers=icon:https://archive.org/download/delivery_marker/delivery_marker.png%7C13.0962573,80.2495762999999&key=AIzaSyCloJwYPYL4Waex5N8asdKgx9tDhXS3IX8&path=color:0x2a5298FF%7Cweight:5%7Cenc:%7BlmnAezzhNpBfA%60CjA~Bj@f@Ht@BlBB%60IJbFDfDDFAPGLAvJHpAHlAYf@O%5CALFLNDFH%5EAHCRMb@OXyBaA_@IiAKaMMsC@qFEaNS_AMe@Ky@Yk@[uA%7B@cK%7DFgAeAUKo@k@cBgB_@*@a@[WMQEA]BMJM%60FPd@@EmAQqC?iARoAl@%7DCNkA@WEcBSgBWm@Ua@qCqDiEyFeDeEcB%7BBkEqGiDiFS*@cBqBOKeCu@wBq@cBi@%7B@*@uB%7B@a@Me@SoEqAuDw@cB]s@YCGmDgBQGOEm@AeCNqDLq@LY?s@IsB]mBWoFg@uA]cCw@[?iAQkCe@iB*@iA[eAS%7BAOuB]%7BMkA?@CBC@I@OGEGyDm@yAOEE%7DGm@%7BIm@yJq@oMcA%7BIy@iH%7D@_LuAcLsAeEi@iMcBwCe@aAOYBgBQuL_BkDc@YCk@CiHeA_QsCiCSYHe@Ho@AOCUIuDh@w@v@cAnAqC%60Dg@b@oA%7C@a@RoDvAmC%7C@s@ZILIXQN_Ab@%7D@p@%7DBdCu@Xa@Fc@@]Cq@Om@a@kAaAy@DQHMHJlDVfFH%7CBN%60B%5ErHp@nFUhCE%7C@@t@PfBVtBj@bERdAv@nBUBeDZoAHeDRkGh@*Hn@yCBSDg@NiAb@]PWJ[DuBE%7BIWc@?SBIBWPORMT?BCFKFOAkCAuBKWCOAEFEFe@l@]V%7DErBSH*@Ni@p@[Rq@~AYt@o@xBOp@aAzDcAbBeAxAi@v@u@hB%7B@zB%7B@zBd@H%5EB%5C?qA~Hg@dDWlC@%60DExAOlBI~BGjCBpAElCEvBO%7CCc@vJEr@Y%5EWZb@bANb@P%7C@nCBfDNE%60A@%60@B%5E](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=13.0171749,80.2604959%7C13.0962573,80.2495762999999&size=400x400&markers=icon:https://ia601509.us.archive.org/18/items/pickup_20180122/pickup.png%7C13.0171749,80.2604959&markers=icon:https://archive.org/download/delivery_marker/delivery_marker.png%7C13.0962573,80.2495762999999&key=AIzaSyCloJwYPYL4Waex5N8asdKgx9tDhXS3IX8&path=color:0x2a5298FF%7Cweight:5%7Cenc:%7BlmnAezzhNpBfA%60CjA~Bj@f@Ht@BlBB%60IJbFDfDDFAPGLAvJHpAHlAYf@O%5CALFLNDFH%5EAHCRMb@OXyBaA_@IiAKaMMsC@qFEaNS_AMe@Ky@Yk@[uA%7B@cK%7DFgAeAUKo@k@cBgB_@_@a@[WMQEA]BMJM%60FPd@@EmAQqC?iARoAl@%7DCNkA@WEcBSgBWm@Ua@qCqDiEyFeDeEcB%7BBkEqGiDiFS_@cBqBOKeCu@wBq@cBi@%7B@_@uB%7B@a@Me@SoEqAuDw@cB]s@YCGmDgBQGOEm@AeCNqDLq@LY?s@IsB]mBWoFg@uA]cCw@[?iAQkCe@iB_@iA[eAS%7BAOuB]%7BMkA?@CBC@I@OGEGyDm@yAOEE%7DGm@%7BIm@yJq@oMcA%7BIy@iH%7D@_LuAcLsAeEi@iMcBwCe@aAOYBgBQuL_BkDc@YCk@CiHeA_QsCiCSYHe@Ho@AOCUIuDh@w@v@cAnAqC%60Dg@b@oA%7C@a@RoDvAmC%7C@s@ZILIXQN_Ab@%7D@p@%7DBdCu@Xa@Fc@@]Cq@Om@a@kAaAy@DQHMHJlDVfFH%7CBN%60B%5ErHp@nFUhCE%7C@@t@PfBVtBj@bERdAv@nBUBeDZoAHeDRkGh@_Hn@yCBSDg@NiAb@]PWJ[DuBE%7BIWc@?SBIBWPORMT?BCFKFOAkCAuBKWCOAEFEFe@l@]V%7DErBSH_@Ni@p@[Rq@~AYt@o@xBOp@aAzDcAbBeAxAi@v@u@hB%7B@zB%7B@zBd@H%5EB%5C?qA~Hg@dDWlC@%60DExAOlBI~BGjCBpAElCEvBO%7CCc@vJEr@Y%5EWZb@bANb@P%7C@nCBfDNE%60A@%60@B%5E)